# In Bootstrap, how to "Stack" buttons in sm mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three buttons that are displayed inline when in md mode. But for sm and xs mode, I want them to stack on each other. Can someone help?

```css
.margin{
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="btn-toolbar-vertical">
  <input class="margin btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block-md" type="button" id="btn1" value="Primary Button" />
  <input class="margin btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block-md" type="button" id="btn1" value="Secondary Button" />
  <input class="margin btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block-md" type="button" id="btn1" value="Cancel Button" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reasons I can't attach the screen shots: so here they are: Basically I don't want to have screen 3 in between: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZHqg.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Riql.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fZvq.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know bootstrap breakpoints for media queries http://getbootstrap.com/css/

You can use it to change the way buttons are displayed on small and extra small devices like that:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { 
  .btn-toolbar-vertical > .btn{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeKQMj

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Lucka, How come I can't do the same for link-button?http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMXzzx  the link button expands. I looked it up to use inline-block, but it ruined the stacks, and I can't just make set a max-width since the content might be long. Any idea?

Comment: Try to change `display: block;` to `display: table;`. If I understand you correctly, it could help.